# How to call webservices method from stand alone application

Tags: java, web-services

I'm facing problem to call a cxf webservices method from standalone java application and want to pass a pojo class object parameter to that method.

Comment: So i guess you call your webservice with and HTTP request. You can try to send the object as Data by serializing it. To any format you want (JSON, XML, etc...) and then unserialize it in your webservice.

Comment: @John I think asking for some helpful suggestion to expert is not bad, this is my part of work so I will update .Don't mind you should not use such type of words.

Comment: Huh? What did I say? Did I say: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys. Finally I resolve the problem. I have used following steps to create stand alone java client for cxf webservices.

step 1:

Create a java project and pojo class same name present at webservice (which object you want to pass to calling webservice method).Ex

```
public class Client{
private String name;

// getter and setter
}
```

Step 2: Create Service  end point Interface having same name()

```
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public interface CheckWebservice {
public boolean isWebservice(Client client);
}
```

Step 3: Now we will call webservice method using spring ApplicationContext so create a application-beans.xml file and put in your project directory(any folder of project)

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">
<jaxws:client id="decisionBean" serviceClass="com.cxf.client.CheckWebservice"
    address="http://localhost:8080/CXF-WEBSERVICES/services/CheckDecisionImplPort" />
```

Step 4: use below code to call webservice running on server.

```
try{
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("demo/xml/application-beans.xml");
    CheckWebservice checkDecision = (CheckWebservice ) context.getBean("decisionBean");

    // Populate the Order bean
    Client decision = new Client();
    decision.setDecision("Decision test");
    boolean checkDcn = checkDecision.isWebservice(decision);
    System.out.println("Decision recived : "+checkDcn);
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note: Please use libraries present in apache-cxf-2.7.7 libs, it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Apache CXF provides several client implementations. You can use one of them. Or if it's a RESTful, JSON based service, you can use any one of many existing clients, or even roll your own using something like GSON and Apache HttpComponents. If it's SOAP, it's a lot more complicated.

Comment: Yes Mikkel that is the problem :(

Comment: Not really. It just takes a little more work to setup: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/dynamic-clients.html

Comment: I suppose if you're trying to call it from something that isn't Java this answer isn't particularly useful. :(